# Looping through a dictionary of lists to plot subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to plot 10 charts. I have created the figure using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 2, figsize=(11,11))
```

I have a dictionary with 10 keys, each containing a dataframe related to that key. I would like to create a subplot for each key, having a barplot for one of the columns in the dataframe. I tried using a for loop like below but can't figure this problem out. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
for key, value in breed_dict.items():
    ax = value.plot(1, 1, kind='bar')
```

I know this isn't close but I am completely stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Dataframe, or Series? If it's a dataframe I believe you'd need to index the value to the series that you'd want.  
`value[4].plot(1,1,kind='bar')`

Comment: Did I answer your question..?

Answer (score 1):

Let the dictionary be `dictOfDF`

```
dictOfDF = { 1:df1 , 2:df2 , ... , 10:df10}
```

Iterate through the subplots in the following manner:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(2):
        subplot = ax[i,j]
```

To access each individual `DataFrame`, just iterate through the `key` of the `dictOfDF`

Now, access each index in the `dfAtKey` and plot it to the `subplot`

```
for ind in dfAtKey.index:
    subplot.bar( dfAtKey.loc[ind,0] , dfAtKey.loc[ind,1] , width = 0.5 )
```

---

So, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 2, figsize=(11,11))    

dictOfDF = { 1:df1 , 2:df2 , ... , 10:df10 }

key = 1
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(2):
        subplot = ax[i,j]

        dfAtKey = dictOfDF[key]

        for ind in dfAtKey.index:
            subplot.bar( dfAtkey.loc[ind,0] , dfAtKey.loc[ind,1] , width = 0.5 )

        key += 1
```

---

Hope this helps